# Power Automate Desktop - Copy Specific Columns

Tags: power-automate-desktop

Hi there and thank you in advance.

I am trying to copy specific columns of data that are not next to each other from an Excel file including their headers and eventually write them into a csv.

What is the best approach?

I have seen suggestions for variables, loops and lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQL to get your desired result.

You can use an excel spreadsheet like a Ace SQL table (Access Database)

see [Run Sql Queries in Power Automate Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/how-to/sql-queries-excel)

Copy the *'code'* below and paste it into power automate desktop.
You will have to fix the errors that show up related to file paths.

```
SET Excel_File_Path TO $'''H:\\Temp\\SOAnswer.xlsx'''

SET csvFilePath TO $'''H:\\Temp\\SOAnswer.csv'''

Database.Connect ConnectionString: $'''Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=%Excel_File_Path%;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";''' Connection=> SQLConnection

Database.ExecuteSqlStatement.ConnectAndExecute ConnectionString: SQLConnection Statement: $'''SELECT [Value] & \', \' & [Check] & \', \' & [Additional Data] as CSV
FROM [List1$]''' Timeout: 30 Result=> QueryResult

Database.Close Connection: SQLConnection

Variables.CreateNewList List=> HeadersList

Variables.AddItemToList Item: $'''Value, Check, Additional Data''' List: HeadersList

File.WriteToCSVFile.WriteCSV VariableToWrite: HeadersList CSVFile: csvFilePath CsvFileEncoding: File.CSVEncoding.UTF8 IncludeColumnNames: False IfFileExists: File.IfFileExists.Append ColumnsSeparator: File.CSVColumnsSeparator.SystemDefault

File.WriteToCSVFile.WriteCSV VariableToWrite: QueryResult CSVFile: csvFilePath CsvFileEncoding: File.CSVEncoding.UTF8 IncludeColumnNames: False IfFileExists: File.IfFileExists.Append ColumnsSeparator: File.CSVColumnsSeparator.SystemDefault

# Clean up the "" at the beginning and end of each line
File.ReadTextFromFile.ReadText File: csvFilePath Encoding: File.TextFileEncoding.UTF8 Content=> csvFileContents

Text.Replace Text: csvFileContents TextToFind: $'''\"''' IsRegEx: False IgnoreCase: False ReplaceWith: $'''%''%''' ActivateEscapeSequences: False Result=> csvFileContents

File.WriteText File: csvFilePath TextToWrite: csvFileContents AppendNewLine: True IfFileExists: File.IfFileExists.Overwrite Encoding: File.FileEncoding.Unicode
```

it should end up looking something like this.

[image]

the dummy data from excel looked like this.

[image]

The result.

[image]

Keep in mind that the SQL used for this is Access SQL flavour, so you won't have all the functionality of MS SQL Server queries, but it sure beats having to run several list extractions and looping through them.